# Why wont it loop?

Tags: java, loops, drop-down-menu, joptionpane

Thank you so much but now it not adding the correct price its keeping it at the first added amount  for example it should be 6.99 +.20 +.20+.20 depending on how many I add

```
 public void addToppings() 
        {
            String[] topChoice = {"Pepperoni", "Mushrooms", "Pineapple", "Bacon", "Beef Bites(IDK)"};
            int add;
            String topPick = " ";
            String total = " ";
            double price = 0;
            int index = 0;

                do 
                    {
                       topPick = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What toppings do you want?","Add Your Toppings", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, topChoice, topChoice[0]);

                       if ((topPick != null) && (topPick.length() > 0))
                                {
                                    price += 0.20;
                                    index++;
                                }

                    add = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like to add more toppings?","More Toppings",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);           
                    }


                while (add == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

                    return;
   }
```

Comment: What is your question? what is your issue?

Comment: I cant get it to loop correctly i think its a logic error

Comment: When you step through the code in your debugger do you see `add` being set to the same value as `YES_OPTION`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line

```
topPick = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What toppings do you want?","Add Your Toppings", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, topChoice, topChoice[0]);
```

into your `do while` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much but now it not adding the correct price its keeping it at the first added amount  for example it should be 6.99 +.20 +.20+.20 depending on how many I add

Comment: you have to set the "base price" without toppings somewhere

Comment: i did  i set at 0 double price = 0;

Comment: yeah i know. But then the price would be .40 if you add 2 toppings, for example.

Comment: so where's the problem?